# notification when in range of cellular signal, or graph or monitor cellular signal strength over time

Tags: iphone, wifi, signal-strength

Dream is to have iPhone notify me when I am back in cellular signal range. Standard iOS notification would be great. Sending a text or email would also be fine.

However, any kind of monitoring and/or graphing cellular signal strength over time would suit my purpose.

I do not need to see my signal strength when I'm paying attention. I need to see it when I'm *not* paying attention. Therefore iOS [field test mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/252949/how-to-access-your-iphones-field-test-mode-and-see-your-real-signal-strength/) doesn't help.

I have a bunch of system utilities downloaded that show information about the cellular signal, including whether it's on or off, but none have any graphing or monitoring capabilities, it seems.

I considered Shortcuts but I am behind (iOS 12.0) and Automation (triggered shortcuts) were introduced only in iOS 13. However in Shortcuts in iOS 12, no system utilities were available to get data from anyway. Maybe that changed in iOS 13? (I can't upgrade to 13 yet because an app I need is not compatible yet.)

I considered IFTTT (If This Then That) but that seems entirely focused on web apps, and can not trigger based on an app running locally on your phone, it seems.

So, I'm out of ideas.

BACKGROUND: I have bad cell service in my basement office--most often zero (0) bars and a "No Service" indicator. So I'm using Verizon WiFi calling, since my WiFi router is right next to me. That mostly works, but calls are dropping after 1 to 30 minutes. [This thread](https://community.verizonwireless.com/t5/Apple-General/iPhone-drops-calls-when-using-wifi-calling/td-p/938992) on the problem suggests that maybe what happens is that cell service pops in for a second, iPhone switches my call from WiFi calling back over to regular cellular calling, but this newly discovered, non-zero cellular signal is either too weak or too short-lived to sustain a phone call, and the call drops.

I'd just like to test that theory by looking at what the cellular signal strength was when the call dropped. Was it non-zero?

Possible?